# android httpURLConnection - getHeaderField

Tags: android, httpurlconnection

I have wrote an app to download photo from internet and parts of the codes is listed as follow:

```
try {


        Log.d("LoadImageFromURL.url", url); 

        url=url.replace(" ", "+");    

        Log.d("LoadImageFromURL.url", url); 



        HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(url).openConnection();
        connection.setUseCaches(true); 
        String contentType = connection.getHeaderField("Content-Type");
        boolean isImage = contentType.startsWith("image/");

        Log.d("Image size", Long.toString(connection.getContentLength())); 
        Log.d("LoadImageFromURL", "getHeaderField Complete"); 


        if(isImage){


            use httpGet to download the photo.... 

}
```

Now, I have facing two problem :

1) if there is a space in the URL (i.e. http://www.abc.com/123 45.jpg), the code will  replace the space to "+" (i.e. http://www.abc.com/123+45.jpg). But the result is return null.

2)It gets 20 second to get the HeaderField, it is too slow. I try to skip this process and the download photo will complete in a few second.

N.B. the size of the photo is 1005511 bytes only. Any ideas?

Comment: in problem one, the result return null means the size of the downloaded photo is null....

Comment: why you have use `url=url.replace(" ", "+");` instead of `url=url.replace(" ", "%20");` ?

Comment: thank you very much! problem one fixed.......

Comment: What happened with the null value at getHeaderFields() ?